# importXML xPath: Retrieve stock information from website to Google Sheets

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets

How can I retrieve the EPS stock information from this website via Google Sheets?
http://seekingalpha.com/symbol/KO

What I would like to output in Google Sheets is this value:

```
1.66
```

On the site I believe that the relevant XML Code to pull that information from is this:

```
<span class="right" id="qp_eps">1.66</span>
```

This Google Sheet formula does not return anything than an error:

```
=ImportXML("http://seekingalpha.com/symbol/KO/focus", "//span[@id='qp_eps'")
```

Comment: Shouldn't your xpath look like : `//span[@id='qp_eps']/text()` also what if there are thousands of `span` elements with attributes `id="qp_eps"`

Comment: I haven't been in touch with xPath before and basically have no idea of it. I tried your proposal but this is also not retrieving anything, unfortunately

Comment: do you know if there is only one span with id = 'qp_eps' in that link ?

Comment: Well, in the DOM Explorer in Microsoft Edge I can only find it once

Comment: Have you tried to verify that the HTML/DOM you see in a browser after the page is loaded, is the same as the original HTML fetched from the URL you gave to `ImportXML()`? It looks to me like the original HTML has no span with `id='qp_eps'`. It must be added later by Javascript or something. Therefore it will not be loaded by `ImportXML()`.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML/DOM that you see in the browser developer tools is not the original HTML received from the web server; it has been augmented dynamically by Javascript running in the browser.

You can check this going to the URL you're importing (http://seekingalpha.com/symbol/KO/focus) in a browser and doing a "Save" (HTML only). Then examine the saved file. It doesn't contain any element with `id="qp_eps"`, does it?

If you have `curl` or `wget`, you can use them instead to fetch the original HTML from the web server and verify what it contains. This is the HTML that `ImportXML()` sees, so you'll have to write your XPath with this HTML in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I Have a workaround for you:

Using IMPORTDATA instead of IMPORTXML, you can use Index which oddly, even with different tickers, is quite consistent:

There are two ways to go about it - First is using Index twice:

```
=INDEX(SORT(INDEX(IMPORTDATA("http://seekingalpha.com/symbol/KO"),,55)),3)
```

And if you want to clean it up to only return the value you can substitute the "eps:" portion:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(SORT(INDEX(IMPORTDATA("http://seekingalpha.com/symbol/KO"),,55)),3),"eps:","")
```

Second is to use index again but instead of Indexing twice, you can just join the values and regex out what you want:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(CONCATENATE(SORT(INDEX(IMPORTDATA("http://seekingalpha.com/symbol/AAPL"),,55))),"eps:(.*)NOW_P")
```

Here are two screenshot of the two types:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Terrific stuff that it works for you :). I have a problem as I only receive "NOW_P:-0.01" with the SUBSTITUTE formula and a "#N/A" with the REGEXTRACT formula. I presume it has something to do with formatting perhaps? Apart from that I was wondering what the "55" and "3" stand for as I would like to retrieve more information e.g. "P/E" from that site using the same principle. However, right now I am stuck but I guess it can only be a minor issue. Thanks so much!!!!

Comment: oh yeah the 55 was an index, so if you use importdata all by itself  youll see a ton of what appears to be unstructured data but the reason I didnt just mash it all into one cell is that it exceeds the character limit - so for example if you reduce the formula to `=SORT(INDEX(IMPORTDATA("http://seekingalpha.com/symbol/KO"),,55))` you will see a sorted list of the column with the values I think you want

Comment: The 3 then just narrows it down further - if you have a sheet you are working out of I can jump in for a second and show you