# Access field with xpath/scrapy in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I would like to use xpath in scrapy with python to get a value from a website. When I try the following path: `//td[@data-reactid=".11g4qq2rc3k.1.$0.0.0.3.1.$main-0-Quote-Proxy.$main-0-Quote.0.2.1.$keyStatistics.1:$key-stats-0.0.0.$1PE_RATIO.1"]/text()` in XPathChecker I get the value that I want. However, when I use the same path in the code it returns []. Here is the code:

```
import scrapy

from tutorial.items import AmgenFinance

class YfinanceSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'yfinance'
    allowed_domains = ['www.yahoo.com']
    start_urls = ['http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMGN']

    def parse(self, response):
        PE = response.xpath("//td[@data-reactid='.11g4qq2rc3k.1.$0.0.0.3.1.$main-0-Quote-Proxy.$main-0-Quote.0.2.1.$keyStatistics.1:$key-stats-0.0.0.$1PE_RATIO.1']/text()")
        print (str(PE))
```

Does anyone know why it's not working? Thanks for all the help.

Cheers

[image]

Comment: you should use simple quotes for your string, and double quotes for your value. `'//td[@data-reactid=".11g4qq2rc3k.1.$0.0.0.3.1.$main-0-Quote-Proxy.$main-0-Quote.0.2.1.$keyStatistics.1:$key-stats-0.0.0.$1PE_RATIO.1"]/text()'`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried, but it does't help. Still I get [].

Comment: can you edit your question showing the working call with XPathChecker too? The more details we get the better. Also have you checked with test paths, maybe simpler?

Comment: try a more broad xpath

Comment: I added the screenshot of xpathchecker.

Comment: Have you verified that the HTML response that scrapy receives from its web query is the same as the HTML you're testing in the browser? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/38383685/423105 for details.